# Gem install rqr Error?

Tags: ruby, compilation, rubygems

i got an error when i install rqr
did anyone know the reason about this comiling error?

```
---> lib
---> lib/rqr
<--- lib/rqr
<--- lib
---> ext
---> ext/rqr
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby /home/bulleric/Desktop/rqr-0.2.2/ext/rqr/extconf.rb
checking for jpeglib.h... yes
checking for main() in -ljpeg... yes
checking for png.h... yes
checking for main() in -lpng... yes
checking for tiff.h... yes
checking for main() in -ltiff... yes
creating Makefile
<--- ext/rqr
<--- ext
---> lib
---> lib/rqr
<--- lib/rqr
<--- lib
---> ext
---> ext/rqr
make
g++ -I. -I/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I/home/bulleric/Desktop/rqr-0.2.2/ext/rqr -DHAVE_JPEGLIB_H -DHAVE_PNG_H -DHAVE_TIFF_H    -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long  -fPIC -DUSE_JPG -DUSE_PNG -DUSE_TIFF   -o qr_wrap.o -c qr_wrap.cxx
qr_wrap.cxx: In function ‘VALUE SWIG_Ruby_NewPointerObj(void*, swig_type_info*, int)’:
qr_wrap.cxx:1306:43: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘ptr’
qr_wrap.cxx: In function ‘int SWIG_AsCharPtrAndSize(VALUE, char**, size_t*, int*)’:
qr_wrap.cxx:1616:30: error: ‘STR2CSTR’ was not declared in this scope
qr_wrap.cxx:1618:33: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘len’
make: *** [qr_wrap.o] Error 1
setup.rb:655:in `command': system("make") failed (RuntimeError)
    from setup.rb:664:in `make'
    from setup.rb:1258:in `setup_dir_ext'
    from setup.rb:1532:in `block in traverse'
    from setup.rb:1549:in `dive_into'
    from setup.rb:1530:in `traverse'
    from setup.rb:1534:in `block (2 levels) in traverse'
    from setup.rb:1533:in `each'
    from setup.rb:1533:in `block in traverse'
    from setup.rb:1549:in `dive_into'
    from setup.rb:1530:in `traverse'
    from setup.rb:1524:in `block in exec_task_traverse'
    from setup.rb:1519:in `each'
    from setup.rb:1519:in `exec_task_traverse'
    from setup.rb:1246:in `exec_setup'
    from setup.rb:996:in `exec_setup'
    from setup.rb:813:in `invoke'
    from setup.rb:773:in `invoke'
    from setup.rb:1578:in `<main>'
```

Is there any libary or  packet not installed or got i a problem with my environment?.

My System
Ubuntu  64bit  11/04

Thank you for your help
Greez Bull

Answer (score 5):

The *rqr* gem is not compatible with Ruby 1.9.  Use the *rqr19* gem instead.

If you are using Bundler, then change the rqr line of your Gemfile from:

```
gem 'rqr'
```

to

```
gem 'rqr19', :require => 'rqr'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on a linux did you install the prerequisites beforehand as stated on the [RQR website](http://rqr.rubyforge.org/)?

```
# 1. Install the prerequisites for Linux
sudo yum install libjpeg
sudo yum install libpng
sudo yum install libtiff

# 2. Then install the gem
sudo gem update --system
sudo gem install rqr
```

I hope this helps